# How to implement push notification support in Cordova app using Quickblox?

Tags: javascript, cordova, quickblox

Apologies for such a basic question, but I really can't find any information on the subject.

The Quickblox Javascript SDK has some classes related to push notifications, and I have enabled them using chat_history and the alerting tab in chat. However what I don't understand is how to receive these notifications on the front end UI?

I don't have any code to share as I don't know where to start!

Any help would be truly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I stated in my question that I have, thus far, been unable to find resources specifically for my issue. I can find the android/ios sdks info for quickblox but struggling to find resources for the JS SDK. Your comment is neither intelligent or constructive. Flagged as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are modules to work with pushes:

```
QB.messages.tokens
QB.messages.subscriptions
QB.messages.events
```

To subscribe for pushes you have to do 2 things:

1. Create a push token using QB.messages.tokens
2. Create a subscription using QB.messages.subscriptions

Additional info can be found in REST API page http://quickblox.com/developers/Messages#Typical_use_.D1.81ases

Also you have to upload APNS and Google API key to QuickBlox admin panel.

This all needs if you are going to build Cordova app for iOS/Android

Comment: Ah fantastic, thank you very much for the advice! Enjoy the rep :D

Comment: Hello, sorry to revive an old post, but would appreciate some help!

Where do i get the client_identification_sequence? I don't understand how to obtain this! I've uploaded the certs to QB admin. Thank you

Comment: client_identification_sequence is a push device token for iOS and registrationId for Android

Answer (score 0):

1. You need encode the message.
2. You need to make sure your mobile app would know to understand the decoded message.

For example,

sending push notification to android qb_user_id: 20290
(and from me - my qb_user_id: 12121):

```
function b64EncodeUnicode(str) {
return btoa(encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g, function(match, p1) {
    return String.fromCharCode('0x' + p1);
}));
}
function send_push() {
var params = {
    notification_type: 'push',
    push_type: 'gcm',
    user: {ids: [20290]},
    environment: "production", 
    message: b64EncodeUnicode('{"message":"HELLO WORLD","user_id":12121,"device_type":"WEB","message_qb_id":"563a55a44cedaa83885724cf","message_type":"Text","send_status":"BeingProcessed","send_time":1446663588607}')
  };

  QB.messages.events.create(params, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("QB.messages.events.create::error:" +err);
    } else {
      console.log("QB.messages.events.create::response:" + response);
    }
  });
 }
```

In this example, the mobile app is looking for a message in this format:
{"message","user_id","device_type","message_qb_id","message_type","send_status","send_time"}